# SQL Server query to generate dynamic staff attendance report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table to store staff attendance which has the following columns:

- id: int, pk
- StaffName: varchar
- CompanyName: varchar
- isPresent: varchar
- date: datetime

How do I write a query which gives attendance of a month?

Eg: Generate report for April for a company XYZ, which should looks like

```
StaffName       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9....up to last day of month
--------------------------------------------------------------
John lenon      p p p a p a a p a....
Bob Dylan       a a a p p p p p a....
Keith Moon      p p p p a p a p p....
```

Comment: what you tried? can you post your table script?

Comment: i have some data like

1   John Lennon    xyz  p    5/1/2013

2   John Lennon    xyz  p    5/2/2013

3   Bob Dylan      Dyl  a    5/1/2013

4   Bob Dylan      Dyl  a    5/2/2013

5   Keith Moon     xyz  p    5/1/2013

6   Keith Moon     xyz  p    5/2/2013


i want to generate report like i hsaid in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be a little bit tricky with qynamic queries. For the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[attendance](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StaffName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [isPresent] [char](1) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ( [id] ASC )
)
go
```

The following script generates 'pivot-compatible' script with days as columns

```
--report params
DECLARE @month int, @year int, @lastDay int
set @month = 1 
set @year = 2012


-- calculations
DECLARE @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime
SET @startDate =  convert(varchar, @year) + '-' + convert(varchar, @month) + '-1'
set @endDate = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,0))
set @lastDay =  day(@endDate) --last day of month

print('showing data from ' + convert(varchar, @startDate) + ' to ' + convert(varchar, @endDate))
print('original report')
SELECT StaffName, isPresent, day([date]) as day FROM attendance
where [date] between @startDate and @endDate

declare @day int
set @day = 2


declare @days varchar(max)
set @days = '[1]'
WHILE (@day <= @lastDay)
BEGIN
   set @days = @days + ',[' + convert(varchar, @day) + ']'
   set @day = @day + 1
END

-- select @days

declare @query varchar(max)

set @query = '
SELECT StaffName, ' + @days  +
'
FROM
(SELECT StaffName, isPresent, day(date) as day FROM attendance) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(isPresent)
FOR day IN ( ' + @days + ')' + '
) AS PivotTable;'

--select @query

print('pivoted report')    
exec(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you very much. it solved my problem. Feeling well now.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot your date as column with the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) functionality(here a quick and dirty example, you may check date format and order):

```
SELECT StaffName, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4] and so on...
FROM
(SELECT StaffName, isPresent, date FROM myTable) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(isPresent)
FOR date IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4] and so on...)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: how to get the list of day from inserted data of the particular month.

Comment: @barcanoj specify your format so I'm able to set some parametric query.